# Get and set in js using function constructors

Tags: javascript

this is my code

```js
function Choices(questions, options, yourChoices) {
  this.questions = questions;
  this.options = options;
  this.yourChoices = yourChoices;
};

Choices.prototype.DisplayChoices = function() {
  console.log(this.questions)
  for (var i = 0; i < this.options.length; i++) {
    console.log(i + ':' + this.options[i]);
  }
}

Choices.prototype.getChoices = function(opt) {
  if (opt == this.yourChoices) {
    console.log('Wow,' + this.options + ' is your favaroite!');
  } else {
    console.log('Choose Wisely')
  }
}

var c1 = new Choices('Which is your most likely Food?', ['Paneer', 'Mutton', 'Chicken'], ['1', '2', '3'])

var c2 = new Choices('Which is your most likely Color?', ['Orange', 'red', 'blue'], ['1', '2', '3'])

var choices = [c1, c2];
var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
choices[n].DisplayChoices();
var getChoice = parseInt(prompt('Please Select any of your Options..'));
choices[n].getChoices(getChoice);
```

well tried to do this but i always get choose wisely and the condition in if statement is always false... what should i do please help!! thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to this line:

```
if(opt == this.yourChoices)
```

**this.yourChoices** is an array which cant be equal to a single number i-e **opt**. Remove this condition and your code will work. if user enter wrong number then this.options[opt] is *undefined*. Hence make a check. `if(this.options[opt])` to check whether it is undefined or not.

```js
function Choices(questions,options,yourChoices) {
    this.questions = questions;
    this.options = options;
    this.yourChoices = yourChoices;  
};
Choices.prototype.DisplayChoices = function(){
    console.log(this.questions)
    for(var i = 0; i < this.options.length; i++){
        console.log(i +':'+ this.options[i]);
    }
}
Choices.prototype.getChoices = function(opt){
    if(this.options[opt]){
        console.log('Wow,'+this.options[opt]+' is your favaroite!');
        }else{
        console.log("choose wisely");
        }
        
    }

var c1 = new Choices('Which is your most likely Food?',
                    ['Paneer','Mutton','Chicken'],
                    ['1','2','3']
                    )

var c2 = new Choices('Which is your most likely Color?',
                    ['Orange','red','blue'],
                    ['1','2','3']
                    )

 var choices = [c1, c2];
var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
choices[n].DisplayChoices();
var getChoice = parseInt(prompt('Please Select any of your Options..'));
  choices[n].getChoices(getChoice);
```

Comment: hey its working but can u plz briefly explain what if(this.options[opt]) actually does?...

Comment: @ShashankMadan if(this.options[opt]) is checking whether it is undefined or not. It returns false if user enter any option which is out of bound. In your case, it returns false when number is other than 0,1,2.

Comment: thanks so much sir really helpfull tip thanks alot!:)

Answer (score 0):

```
function Choices(questions,options,yourChoices) {
    this.questions = questions;
    this.options = options;
    this.yourChoices = yourChoices;  
};
Choices.prototype.DisplayChoices = function(){
    console.log(this.questions)
    for(var i = 0; i < this.options.length; i++){
        console.log(i +':'+ this.options[i]);
    }
}
Choices.prototype.getChoices = function(opt){
console.log(opt,this.yourChoices);
        if(this.yourChoices[opt]){ // (opt == this.yourChoices) this condition is not right because opt is integer and this.yourChoices is object
        console.log('Wow,'+this.options[opt-1]+' is your favaroite!');
    }else{
        console.log('Choose Wisely')
    }
    }

var c1 = new Choices('Which is your most likely Food?',
                    ['Paneer','Mutton','Chicken'],
                    ['1','2','3']
                    )

var c2 = new Choices('Which is your most likely Color?',
                    ['Orange','red','blue'],
                    ['1','2','3']
                    )

 var choices = [c1, c2];
var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
choices[n].DisplayChoices();
console.log(n);
var getChoice = parseInt(prompt('Please Select any of your Options..'));
  choices[n].getChoices(getChoice);
```

Answer (score 0):

There're two issues:

1. You're comparing the selected choice with the entire array of choices, so you should change this line

   `if(opt == this.yourChoices){`

   with following

   `if(this.yourChoices.indexOf(opt) > -1){`
2. You filled the array with strings (eg: '1','2',...) so you don't have to parse to int the user's choice, so change following:

   `var getChoice = parseInt(prompt('Please Select any of your Options..'));`

   to

   `var getChoice = prompt('Please Select any of your Options..');`

I hope it helps you, bye.